# angular injection when minified

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code works but not when minified... What should I do?
I get this error Error:

$injector:strictdi
Explicit annotation required

// app.js

```
angular
 .module('app', [route, 'templates']);

angular
 .module('app')
 .config(config);

function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $routeProvider

.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}


angular
.module('app')
.controller('HomeController', HomeController);

function HomeController() {
 var vm = this;
 vm.header = 'Home';
}
```

// home.html

```
{{ vm.header }}
```

Comment: This is an ancient problem: https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular tries to implicit loads dependencies by the arguments name and it works fine as long as the argument name is the same as the dependency you want to load.

For example,

```
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    ...
}
```

This will trigger angular to inject the function with the $routeProvider and the $locationProvider but what happens if you minify the code to this:

```
function config(a, b) {
    ...
}
```

Angular will now try to inject the function with a and b (which does not exist). Therefore, you need to explicitly tell angular what dependencies you want to inject. You can either do it with inline bracket notation:

```
// bracket notation
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', config]);

function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    ...
}
```

... or alternatively with the $inject property:

```
// $inject property
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer! If you already have a build process and don't want to type all that stuff by yourself, you should have a look at ng-annotate which can insert this additional information before minification. https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate. The error can be enforced even when not minified by adding the strict-di attribute of the ng-app. This helps catching errors already during development and seems to be activated in the OP's case. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using strict mode (most probably 'use strict' somewhere in code), you must explicitly inject the dependencies.

You can do like this

```
config.$inject = [$routeProvider, $locationProvider];
```

Comment: The message doesn't occur because of a "use strict" directive but is caused by using the ngStrictDi (strict dependency injection) checks, that can be activated by adding the corresponding attribute: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
angular
 .module('app')
  .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider','$locationProvider'];
  function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider

 .when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
     });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}

 })();

   (function () {
  'use strict';

      angular
        .module('plunker')
        .controller('HomeController',HomeController);


      HomeController.$inject = [];
      function HomeController() {

       var vm = this; 
            }

         })();
```